# Bathroom door stuck - locked- the door “knob” can be turned with a screwdriver but doesn’t engage the lock?

Tags: doors

We have tried a paint scraper to engage the lock- we have tried turning the knob with a screwdriver- nothing works- any ideas? I can’t find a similar lock online either[image]

Comment: disassemble the hinges, if possible

Comment: I believe that is a pocket door...no hinges.  Try to lift the door slightly  by prying gently with a tool under the door close to the lock side.

Comment: Is the latch a bolt or is it a hook?

Comment: Brute force prybar time, or a combination of brute force and finesse, depending on what the details of the latch are - but brute force will do if finesse fails.

Comment: Worst case, slip a hacksaw blade in and cut the latch arm.

Comment: Or if you can get into the bathroom via a window, you might find screws on the interior for disassembly.